# Calling char method into main method

Tags: java

How do I call this method into my main method:

```
 public static char shiftLetter(char aLetter, int offset){

    if((aLetter >= 65 && aLetter <= 90) || (aLetter >=97 && aLetter <=122)){
      char shifted = (char) (aLetter + offset);  
      return shifted;
    }else{
      return aLetter;
    }
  }
```

Here is my main method:

```
 public static void main(String[]args){ 
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    String isAnswer = askQ();
    if (isAnswer.equals("encode") || isAnswer.equals("decode")){
      String text = isText();
      int offset = isOffset();
      char[] myString = text.toCharArray();
      System.out.println(myString);
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you if you want to get help mor easily on your further questions.

Answer (score 2):

If `shiftLetter()` method is in the same class than your `main()` method then just type its name to call it :

```
shiftLetter('a', 123);
```

Then if it is another class, in your main you have to put the name of the class before the name of the method :

```
OtherClasse.shiftLetter('a', 123);
```

Answer (score 1):

if shiftLetter is in your main class than you can just use

shiftLetter('a', 4);

where 'a' and 4 are whatever parameters you want. IF it's in a class outside the main class you may have to use Class.ShiftLetter() or import it if it's in another package

Comment: 'foo' is not a character. And if the method is in another class you won't have to import it if it is in the same package...

Comment: Also you won't have to import the method but the class ;)